# Solidity secure user withdrawal with checks/effects/patterns

Tags: security, solidity

Can the checks/effects/interactions pattern be used for refunding users securely (in place of a separate withdraw function)?

EG in the case of a bidding system, where if user 2 outbids user 1 and user 1 receives their money back, is the checks/effects/patterns sufficiently secure to send user 1's money back?

For instance, something like

```
contract auction {
    address highestBidder;
    uint highestBid;

    function bid() payable external {
        require(msg.value >= highestBid);
        prevHighestBidder = highestBidder
        prevHighestBid = highestBid

        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        highestBid = msg.value;
        (bool success, ) = prevHighestBidder.call.value(prevHighestBid)("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.")
    }
}
```

I understand that creating a separate withdraw function is preferred, but I'm hoping to reduce gas costs for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if the receiver (`prevHighestBidder`) is a contract that rejects the transaction? That would effectively break your game as no one after them could successfully call the `bid()` function.

Their contract might be as simple as

```
contract BlockBids {
    function callBid() payable {
        // call the bid() function with value
        address(<yourContract>).call{value: msg.value}('0x1998aeef');
    }

    receive () external payable {
        revert();
    }
}
```

My recommendation is to **NOT** check whether the `prevHighestBidder` received the ETH. Or to add a fallback mechanism that withdraws the ETH to your address in case the receiver rejects the transaction, so that you can send it to them after they prove ownership of the winning address (e.g. by signing a message).

Comment: Got it, that's a good suggestion! If the prevHighestBidder call fails, wouldn't the require(false) revert all state changes? So someone new bidding could still proceed?

Comment: No, anyone else could not proceed... The faulty contract is able to send the bid and set themself as `prevHighestBidder`. So, any other bidder after them would not be able to call the `bid()` function if the `prevHighestBidder` call fails (and the `require` is in place).

Comment: AH. I understand. Since when bidder2 calls in, then the prevHighestBidder call would revert any changes due to failing, so the state variables would never change. Thank you so much for clarifying! So without the require, the function should follow the checks/effects/interactions pattern? Didn't realize require had that unintended side effect.

Comment: Just wanted to say this was super helpful, thanks so much here! I took some sample code from consensys but didn't realize the side effects here. Super helpful in clarifying how I should think about this.